# How to use webservices in a dot NET application?

Tags: .net, web-services, delphi-xe, smartphone, delphi-prism

Say for instance, I have a temperature sensor in my refrigerator which is connected to a computer and has Internet access. I want to be able to inquire the computer for my refrigerator temperature reading through (lets just say) my smartphone remotely (from my office). So, that the sensor reading can be displayed on my smartphone or any hand-held devices. Can you use web services for such scenarios? Just trying to understand how web services fit in with real world scenarios. I am used to programming mostly standalone application.

Comment: Too broad a question. Simple answer is yes. There is a ton of information out there for you to read. Here's a starting point. [Beginner's Guide to Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd939784)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is : Yes you can.
Long answer is: As long as you can establish an http connection between your smartphone and your device, you can use web services to do pretty much what you want. In this scenario, I suspect that finding an easy way to handle passing through one or multiple firewall (assuming you are on your offices wi-fi, there will be 2, your office's and your home's) will be a bigger challenge.